# Can you change the root directory in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've been trying to change the root directory of my jekyll site to another folder but I can't seem to find a way to do this and was wondering if it's possible?
What I want is for all of my html pages to be in a folder named _pages, and for my website to load index.html from this folder. Currently I can only get this working by changing the baseurl and accessing the website by www.domain.com/pages/index.hmtl. Can I have it so the html files remain in this folder, and have jekyll render the site so that I can access index.html from www.domain.com/ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `_config.yml` file you'll need to include the directory where your HTML pages live like this:

```
include: [_pages]
```

In your `_pages/index.html` file include a permalink in the frontmatter like this:

```
---
permalink: /
---
```

Run your Jekyll build command again. If I understand your question correctly, this will output your homepage without needing to have or adjust your baseurl.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing this also by outputting the collection as pages and redirecting with permalinks.
Do you know if there's any way you can put a variable into frontmatter?
I created this to generate permalinks but I can't use the variable "link" in the frontmatter; {% assign link = page.url | strip baseurl %}